# Akka Actor: Remote actor exception "Futures timed out after"

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, scalatest, akka-remote-actor

i am new for Akka, i am using `Akka 2.3.3` version for creating actors. I am going to create remote actor and trying to access with client. Whenever i am going to run test-case, the following exception will throw:

```
[INFO] [04/27/2016 07:51:23.727] [Localsystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Localsystem/deadLetters] Message [com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.messages.SetRequest] from Actor[akka://Localsystem/temp/$a] to Actor[akka://Localsystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [04/27/2016 07:51:23.745] [Localsystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Localsystem/deadLetters] Message [com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.messages.GetRequest] from Actor[akka://Localsystem/temp/$b] to Actor[akka://Localsystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
at com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.SClientIntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SClientIntegrationSpec.scala:18)
at com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.SClientIntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SClientIntegrationSpec.scala:15)
at com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.SClientIntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SClientIntegrationSpec.scala:15)
at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:422)
at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
at com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.SClientIntegrationSpec.withFixture(SClientIntegrationSpec.scala:11)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSpecLike.scala:419)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:431)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:431)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$class.runTest(FunSpecLike.scala:431)
at com.harmeetsingh13.chapter2.SClientIntegrationSpec.runTest(SClientIntegrationSpec.scala:11)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:464)
at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:464)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
............
```

My Server code as below: 
Main.scala

```
object Main extends App{


 private val configFile = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("application.conf").getFile;
 private val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile ))

 val system = ActorSystem("SimpleClientServer", config)
 system.actorOf(Props[AkkadmeyDB], name = "akkademy-db")
}
```

application.conf:

```
akka{
 actor{
  provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
 }
remote{
 enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
  netty.tcp {
   hostname = "127.0.0.1"
   port = 2552
  }
  log-sent-messages = on
  log-received-messages = on
 }
}
```

AkkadmeyDB.scala Actor class:

```
class AkkadmeyDB extends Actor{

 val map = new HashMap[String, Object]
 val log = Logging(context.system, this)

 override def receive: Receive = {
  case SetRequest(key, value) =>
   log.info("received SetRequest - key: {} value: {}", key, value)
   map.put(key, value)
   sender() ! Status.Success
  case GetRequest(key) =>
   log.info("received GetRequest - key: {}", key)
   val response = map.get(key)
   response match{
     case Some(x) => sender() ! x
     case None => Status.Failure(new KeyNotFoundException(key))
   }
   case o => Status.Failure(new ClassNotFoundException())
  }
 }
```

Client Code as below: 
SClient.scala

```
class SClient(remoteIp: String) {

  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
  private implicit val system = ActorSystem("Localsystem")
  private val remoteAddress = s"akka.tcp://SimpleClientServer@$remoteIp/user/akkademy-db";
  private val remoteDb = system.actorSelection(remoteAddress)

  def set(key: String, value: Object) = {
   remoteDb ? SetRequest(key, value)
  }

  def get(key: String) = {
    remoteDb ? GetRequest(key)
  }
}
```

SClientIntegrationSpec.scala Test case:

```
class SClientIntegrationSpec extends FunSpecLike with Matchers {

  val client = new SClient("127.0.0.1:2552")
  describe("akkadment-db-client"){
    it("should set a value"){
      client.set("jame", new Integer(1313))
      val futureResult = client.get("james")
      val result = Await.result(futureResult, 10 seconds)
      result should equal (1313)
    }
  }
}
```

When i see the logs of my remote application, this seems like, the request hit doesn't go to the server. what is the problem in my sample code running?

Comment: hey it's jason goodwin - I saw your tweet. Can you push your code to github? I've checked all of the examples work before publishing that are posted on my github. I'll give you a hand.

Comment: hi @JasonG thanks for you reply. I am not using downloaded code from you repository, i am creating my own according to your chapters. Divide code into two repository server and client. In Server Repo go to Chapter 2 package https://github.com/harmeetsingh0013/Akka-practice-using-scala and Client repo https://github.com/harmeetsingh0013/Akka-practice-using-scala-client. As i mention above, the server code is running successfully, but when i am trying to run client test case, then i got and exception as above mention.

Comment: thanks, i'll check it out later and get back to you.

Comment: Tanks @JasonG, i will be wait for you answer.

Answer (score 4):

For solving above problem, we need to follow two steps that are metnion below:

1. When i am creating a server code, i am excluding `application.conf` from my server application, that's why, client application not able to connect with server. The code are using in `built.sbt` is as below:

   ```
   mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot { case (_, name) =>
    Seq("application.conf").contains(name)
   }}
   ```

After commenting above code, the client see the server successfully.

2. In `Learning Scala` **chapter 2** `jasongoodwin` explain the code of client and server actor system. But there are some Errata in book and missing `application.conf` configuration for client. Because when we run both code in same PC, we are facing already port bind exception because by default actors are using `2552` port for accessing and we already define this port for our server application. So, `application.conf` also need for client as below:

   ```
   akka {
     actor {
       provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
     }
     remote {
       enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
       netty.tcp {
         hostname = "127.0.0.1"
         port = 0
       }
       log-sent-messages = on
       log-received-messages = on
     }
   }
   ```

Here `Port 0` means any free port.

After that, above code are running successfully.

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you follow the code sample given in github rather writing on your own. It will save lot of your time. I am doing the same for java code samples and it has been a smooth journey so far. Yes, you are right, the application.conf for client code was not mentioned in the book. The point to note that client and server both are same and require the remote configuration to be enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application.conf file in the client project as well which is not mentioned in the book.
Make sure you create that file under the resources folder with the following content:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
}
```

See the [official github repo](https://github.com/jasongoodwin/learning-akka/blob/master/ch2/akkademy-db-client-scala/src/main/resources/application.conf)

Comment: Yes, this works. Just note that if you're running the Java example, you may also need to config the port "remote.netty.tcp.port = 0" as shown in the Java example in GitHub, otherwise the first time you run the test if will run fine, but if you re-run without bouncing Activator it will fail on subsequent tries. This setting isn't in the Scala example, which was a bit confusing for me at first. Not sure if that's an oversight, or if it's simply not necessary with Scala. https://github.com/jasongoodwin/learning-akka/blob/master/ch2/akkademy-db-client-java/src/main/resources/application.conf